# I'm trying to see the result of this script, when it runs it closes right away and doesn't show the groups the user was added too

Tags: windows, powershell

This is my script,

I'm trying to add a user to these groups and show the result at the end to which group the user are in.

```
$user =  Read-host "Please enter user"
$groups = 'M365-E3-Laptop-Office-Desktop','M365-E3-Laptop-EXO'
$groupsremove = 'M365-F3-WebOnly-Apps'

foreach($group in $groups){
  Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $user}

foreach($groupsremove in $groupsremove){
  Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupsremove -Members $user}

foreach($user in $groups){
  Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user | select name} 

Start-Sleep -seconds 30
```

Comment: You do not mention the actual issue/error you are running into, can you please clarify?

Comment: Does the script actual successfully run? In other words, what happens when you open de PowerShell console (or ise/terminal) and paste the commands in there?

Answer (score 0):

try this, maybe its case sensitive

```sh
$user =  Read-host "Please enter user"
$groups = 'M365-E3-Laptop-Office-Desktop','M365-E3-Laptop-EXO' $groupsremove = 'M365-F3-WebOnly-Apps'

foreach($group in $groups){ Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $user}

foreach($groupsremove in $groupsremove){ Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupsremove -Members $user}

foreach($user in $groups){Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user | select name} 

Start-Sleep -Seconds 30`
```

Comment: this worked, %{Write-host $_.name};pause

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no need to use ForEach instruction if your variable **$groupsremove** only contains one group.
Second, there is also no need to use ForEach instruction since you only have one user.

```
$user =  Read-host "Please enter user"
$groups = 'M365-E3-Laptop-Office-Desktop','M365-E3-Laptop-EXO'
$groupsremove = 'M365-F3-WebOnly-Apps'

ForEach($group in $groups)
{
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $user
}

Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupsremove -Members $user

Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user | Select-Object Name
```

It should returns you something like this:

```
Name
----
M365-E3-Laptop-Office-Desktop
M365-E3-Laptop-EXO
```

Then, regarding the powershell prompt closing after the script is finished, you could simply call the script through a PowerShell prompt first instead of executing  the script directly from the file, so the window doesn't close at the end.

Comment: Thank you this much cleaner, but prefer to run it as a script instead of opening PS every time.

Comment: Do you know if I could use a display name for the -Identity?